# Unexpected varnish behaviour of regsub

Tags: varnish, regex

According to the varnish [documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/RedirectsAndRewrites), the `regsub` method should not result in a 301 redirect. Yet that is what seems to be happening in my case (that is, the url actually changes in the browser).

This is what my config looks like:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    ...
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/event/([-\w]+)/(.*)/$", "/event/\1");
    ...
}
```

(`/event/testevent/1234/` is redirected to `/event/testevent`)

Behind, I've got nginx and django <kbd>varnish</kbd> -> <kbd>nginx</kbd> -> <kbd>uwsgi</kbd> -> <kbd>django</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see what happened...
Django was appending a slash to the url an doing a redirect.

This does the trick:

```
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/event/([-\w]+)/(.*)/$", "/event/\1/");
```